# [emerg]: host not found in upstream

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm a little confused. I am trying to build a Flask application and am deploying it in a docker image with nginx as the web server. After I run `docker-compose up` I am able to get the containers into a running state but in the output of the command I get the following: `[emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "flask:8000" in in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:12`. The odd thing is if I access `localhost` I'm able to see the application working. I don't know if this is something I need to address, since it's working? Additionally, I'm trying to setup redirects from HTTP to HTTPS, that seems to not work. Below is my docker-compose file and the nginx.conf file, and the docker file I have for the nginx container. Any advice would be helpful.

**Docker Compose**

```
version: "3"
services:
  app:
    build: ./app
    container_name: containerize_app_1
    command: gunicorn --chdir app/src --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 --workers 2 "server:app"
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www
    expose:
      - 8000
    networks:
      - MyNetwork
  nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: containerize_nginx_1
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - app
    networks:
      MyNetwork:
        aliases:
          - flask-app

networks:
  MyNetwork:
```

**nginx.conf**

```
user nginx nginx;
worker_processes 2;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
    worker_connections 4096;
}

http {
  upstream flask-app {
    server app:8000;
  }

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://flask-app;
      proxy_set_header Host "localhost";
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
  }
}
```

**nginx dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

**docker-compose up**

```
docker-compose up
containerize_app_1 is up-to-date
containerize_nginx_1 is up-to-date
Attaching to containerize_app_1, containerize_nginx_1
app_1    | [2021-12-14 21:48:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.9.0
app_1    | [2021-12-14 21:48:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:8000 (1)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 21:48:01 +0000] [1] [INFO] Using worker: sync
app_1    | [2021-12-14 21:48:01 +0000] [12] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 12
app_1    | [2021-12-14 21:48:01 +0000] [13] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 13
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:21:03 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:12)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:21:03 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:13)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:21:03 +0000] [13] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 13)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:21:03 +0000] [12] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 12)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:21:03 +0000] [14] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 14
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:21:04 +0000] [15] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 15
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:27:44 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:14)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:27:44 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:15)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:27:44 +0000] [14] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 14)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:27:44 +0000] [15] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 15)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:27:44 +0000] [16] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 16
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:27:45 +0000] [17] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:32:53 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:16)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:32:53 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:17)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:32:53 +0000] [16] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 16)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:32:53 +0000] [17] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:32:53 +0000] [18] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 18
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:32:53 +0000] [19] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 19
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:42:31 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:18)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:42:31 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:19)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:42:31 +0000] [19] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 19)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:42:31 +0000] [18] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 18)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:42:31 +0000] [20] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 20
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:42:31 +0000] [21] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 21
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:48:26 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:20)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:48:26 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:21)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:48:26 +0000] [21] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 21)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:48:26 +0000] [20] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 20)
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:48:26 +0000] [22] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22
app_1    | [2021-12-14 22:48:26 +0000] [23] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 23
app_1    | [2021-12-15 00:11:42 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:22)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 00:11:42 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:23)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 00:11:42 +0000] [23] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 23)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 00:11:42 +0000] [22] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 22)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 00:11:42 +0000] [24] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 24
app_1    | [2021-12-15 00:11:42 +0000] [25] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 25
app_1    | [2021-12-15 01:55:27 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:24)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 01:55:27 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:25)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 01:55:27 +0000] [24] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 24)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 01:55:27 +0000] [25] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 25)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 01:55:27 +0000] [26] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 26
app_1    | [2021-12-15 01:55:27 +0000] [27] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 27
app_1    | [2021-12-15 02:34:31 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:26)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 02:34:31 +0000] [1] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:27)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 02:34:31 +0000] [27] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 27)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 02:34:31 +0000] [26] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 26)
app_1    | [2021-12-15 02:34:31 +0000] [28] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 28
app_1    | [2021-12-15 02:34:31 +0000] [29] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 29
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx_1  | 2021/12/14 23:37:02 [emerg] 1#1: host not found in upstream "flask:8000" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:12
nginx_1  | nginx: [emerg] host not found in upstream "flask:8000" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:12
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
nginx_1  | 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf is not a file or does not exist
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
nginx_1  | /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
nginx_1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [14/Dec/2021:23:48:17 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 128 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15"
nginx_1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [15/Dec/2021:02:22:03 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 128 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15"
```

Comment: You're missing [`links:`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: Thank you for the insight. The documentation specifies networks should be used over links. Also is links used in version 2 for docker compose. I'm on version 3. What is the benefit of using links?

Comment: @msanford `links:` are an obsolete option and are not necessary on any modern Docker.  (Similarly for `expose:`, actually.)

Comment: The error message you quote doesn't match the config file you show (the error message has a `flask` hostname but the config file shows `app`, and `app` should work).  Do you need to `docker-compose build` the image again, perhaps?

Comment: this may work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73346423/3419751